# how to aggregate columns from multiple tables in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables here and I want to sum up measure 3 and measure 4.

[image: 1]

both the measures are calculated once. I want to show sum against every country I have in the tables eg: `Germany(0.31+0.18= 0.49)`

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[model data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVedV.png)

[new result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFj3J.png)

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Also Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: Measure3 and Measure4 in separate table?

Comment: yes, in separate tables.

Comment: You can merge 2 tables first into 1 table. Then create Measure 3 and 4 and then you can create another measure with Measure3*Measure4.

Comment: Another option- create Measure3 and Measure4 as Custom Column instead of Measure. There might some adjustment needed in Measure 3 and 4 code. If they are column, you can create a new Measure using Lookup by Country and Measure3*Measure4.

Comment: these tables are not present in the model. these are created by measures

Comment: Then create combinedly from the beginning.

Comment: can you also help me with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162014/how-to-show-up-measure-value-in-another-table-in-power-bi

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried :

```
NewMeasure := SumX(Filter(Country, AND(Measure4 <> Blank(), Measure3 <> BLANK()) ), MEASURE 3 + MEASURE 4)
```

and then on PowerBi on the data view you select your measure and change the format to be with 2 decimal values.

Comment: this doesn't work, it shows up the same value for every row

Comment: Can you please provide the formula for measure 2 and measure 3.

Comment: Measure 4 = [FTE % Manufacturing]*[Relevance % Manufacturing] - its a calculated measure,  Measure 3 = [FTE % R&D]*[Relevance % R&D]  these are the formulas used for measure 3 and measure 4

Comment: can you post a picture of your data model with the tables and columns involved please. are [FTE % Manufacturing], [Relevance % Manufacturing],[FTE % R&D] and [Relevance % R&D] column name or measure names. If they are columns name I would need the name of the table like in TableName[ColumnName], and the direction of the relationship between those column. Without this information it's difficult to write a formula that's suppose to operate a context transition.

Comment: all are the measures, no columns.

Comment: You see, measure gets evaluated in a context (Filter context + Row context), the reason why it's not working here is because one (all?) of your measure does not operate on this row context which is by country. One way to solve this is to force the row context on each country using an iterator (SumX for example), and filtering (Filter) on country id when you have a value on your fact_table (the table is the table that is on the many side of the relationship), the thing here is that in order to do that I would need to operate a context transition, hence I need to see the table involved.

Comment: SUMX is not working for measures, I tried using that one. I just have two tables. all other tables are created by measures. do you have an example, where I can use filter for measures sum. that would be great, thanks

Comment: Sumx works on measures, however in order to be working they need a row context hence to iterate on a Table. You can mix Sumx with Filter as the later returns a table and Sumx needs to consume a Table a first argument. Can you go to the "model" part of your powerBi and screenshot and update your question with this screenshot. Thank you :)

Comment: @gari that’s not the model you’ve updated, but it seems you only have 1 table.

Comment: yes, correct. all the measures I have calculated using formulas

Comment: Can you try the following :

Comment: Could you try now ?

Comment: thanks again, I tried it but it is still not working

Comment: I have updated, it changed the result but not giving the exact result.

Comment: What value for « New Measure » are you expecting for « United » ?

Comment: for Germany, I am expecting : 0.51, but I am getting 1.17

Comment: @gari how come you’re not expecting 0.49 ?

Comment: sorry, yes 0.49, but I am still not getting the value.